# React useState related issues, When passing an array to it

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

Actually what I am doing is making **flipping cards**. Each time user clicks on the deck a card is revealed and that card is **removed from the deck**.

-Flipping of cards is done but now when the user clicks to open the card it will remove the opened card after 3 seconds and the array will be updated. **But when I am passing my cardsInit which have also isflipping states access is now not opening or flipping the card.**

```
const CardsComp = () => {
  let initState = {
    cardChange: {
      card1: false,
      card2: false,
      card3: false,
      card4: false,
    },
  }
  const [isFlipped, setisFlipped] = useState(initState)
```

**Here is the cardsInit which also contains the isFlipped states access.**

```
  let cardsInit = [
    { id: '1', cardName: 'Cat Card', isCard: isFlipped.cardChange.card1 , cardChange: {card1: !isFlipped.cardChange.card1}},
    { id: '2', cardName: 'Defuse card', isCard: isFlipped.cardChange.card2 , cardChange: {card2: !isFlipped.cardChange.card2}},
    { id: '3', cardName: 'Shuffle card', isCard: isFlipped.cardChange.card3 , cardChange: {card3: !isFlipped.cardChange.card3}},
    { id: '4', cardName: 'Exploding kitten', isCard: isFlipped.cardChange.card4 , cardChange: {card4: !isFlipped.cardChange.card4} },
  ]
```

**But when passing to cardsInit state to cards my opening isFlipped state not working. If I don't use the cards state for controlling the cards array everything works fine.**
*But I want to remove cards from array after user open it.*

```
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(cardsInit)
```

**this is the function I am using for removing the cards after opening them.**

```
  const mySetTimeout = (index) => {
    // setTimeout(() =>{
    // setCards(cards.slice(index,1))
    // },3000)
  }
```

**Iterating through my cards array.**

```
      {cards.map((card, index) => (
        <ReactCardFlip
          key={card.id}
          isFlipped={card.isCard}
          flipDirection="vertical"
        >
```

```
          <div className="front">
            Choose Me!
            <button
              className="bg-red-500 p-2"
              onClick={() => {

// setisFlipped function here....

                setisFlipped({ ...isFlipped, cardChange: card.cardChange })
              }}
            >
              Open
            </button>
          </div>

          <div className="back">
            {card.cardName}
            <button
              className="bg-red-500 p-2"
              onClick={() =>
                setisFlipped({ ...isFlipped, cardChange: card.cardChange })
              }
            >
              Open
            </button>
          </div>
        </ReactCardFlip>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default CardsComp
```

Comment: try `setCards([...cards.slice(index,1)])`.  Im not sure `.slice` returns a new array instance.

Answer (score 0):

to fix the problem with slice use this code.

```
  const mySetTimeout = (index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let array = [...cards];
      array.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(array);
      setCards(array);
    }, 3000);
  };
```

you might have another problem with your code because

```
setisFlipped({ ...isFlipped, cardChange: card.cardChange })
```

is changing the all object to be only something like

```
{
    "cardChange": {
        "card1": true
    }
}
```

consider using an array of false values , and change them by the index. or
using something else that fits your requirements , you can also do fields for every card not inside an cardChange Object.